# How do I emit light from car backlight?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, light, emission

I have been following a tutorial for blender.I am using a 3d model I just download from the internet. However, I cannot seem to emit lights from my car backlight. [image: the model I am working on!]

But the tutorial I am following has a nice light emission from the car.
[image: tutorial I am following.]

How can I tweek a red light from my car? Can anyone guide me where I am missing out?

Comment: Mix an Emission shader with whatever you want, if you want a bit of glow, use the Bloom option, and if you need it to emit on its environment you need to add a Light > Point for example

Comment: It depends on what material the lights are set for. If it’s a Principled BSDF, your work is done. Just turn on the shaders emission strength, and/or change the emission color to red.

Answer (score 0):

noob me here. Finally found where I went wrong. My render engine was Eevee so I switched it back to cycles.

So that's, Render Properties -> Render Engine -> Cycles

lights should be popping out now!